# How to get the text from a specific closest element?

Tags: jquery, html, closest

I've been learning to code by my own and to do some fancy stuff with jquery library but I'm stuck here. This is what I got:

```
<span class='ccy'>San Diego</span><span class='dc'> X</span>
<span class='ccy'>San francisco</span><span class='dc'> X</span>
<span class='ccy'>Palo alto</span><span class='dc'> X</span>
```

I want to be able to click in the $("span.dc") and get only the text() of the < span> next to it (the name of the city), works fine if there is only one city in the html, but as long as I keep adding them up the result gets messy and I end up with a string containing all the city names and I only need one.

I know that the obvious thing would be give them a different id to each one but it'd get even messier 'cause the that html is dynamically generated depending on a previous event triggered by the user, the cities come from an array and I need the individual name of the city to delete from it if 'x' is clicked, I hope I've explained myself good enough.

[jsfiddle here!!](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_39_34/z630dz7L/2/) so you can see better what I mean

Comment: It's *well worth* your time to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two tops, and it pays you back that time almost immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your markup, the simplest is this use of [.prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dc").on("click",function() {
    var city = $(this).prev().text(); 
    console.log(city);
    $("#msg").html("You clicked "+city);
  });
});
```

```css
.dc { padding-right:3px;border-right:1px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='ccy'>San Diego</span><span class='dc'> X</span>
<span class='ccy'>San Francisco</span><span class='dc'> X</span>
<span class='ccy'>Palo Alto</span><span class='dc'> X</span>
<br/><span id="msg"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `prev()` to get previous span.

```
$("span.dc").click(function() {     
   var jj = $(this).prev('span.ccy').text();
});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c8docb5x/)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `.prev('span.ccy')` does **not** mean "the previous span with class `ccy`" but rather "the previous span **if** it has class `ccy`" (e.g., it doesn't scan, it only ever returns the immediately-previous element or none). In this case, there's really no reason to include the selector.

Comment: yes, with this html structure you could just use `$(this).prev()`